# Bricked 10.10 only gives me initramfs

Tags: 10.10, grub2, init, initramfs

I managed to brick my Ubuntu 10.10 laptop after updating to x-swat Nvidia and Intel drivers and now I can only get "init not found" when I boot, and I'm dumped to a initramfs text console. I won't even let me use mount to mount the existing partitions.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll need more details, although I suspect you've already worked through this issue.

Type **dmesg** and append the last few lines output to this bug for more help.